# Apache Rewrite URL - Change parameter to page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this is simple but I am not able to get it right. How to change this:

```
http://example.com/page.php?type=article
```

into

```
http://example.com/page/article
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?type=$1 [NC,B,L]
```

Comment: The value `article` was just as an example. How to change it to be variable?

Comment: I copy and pasted but it doesn't seem to work. My other rules are in `.htaccess` file are working but not this one. If I enter the new URL `http://example.com/page/article` I get the `500 Internal Error`

Comment: If I write `http://example.com/page/article` in the URL, will I be able to retrieve the `value` data from the PHP `$_GET` array?

Comment: edited again, and yea its like your accessing the page.php?type=whatever so you can use the get array

Comment: After applying your code, my CSS and Images have stopped loading. The paths have become invalid

Comment: try it now, the rewriteCond is supposed to prevent the break of the css and images...